# Regex: replace multiple occurrences of a pattern within the same line, using one single regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the %20's in a URL and replace them with +'es, as well as strip away some other stuff, all preferably using a single regular expression.

Specifically, I'd like something like this

`a%20sentence%20divided%20by%20spaces_123456.html`

to be turned into something like this

`a+sentence+divived+by+spaces`

**Edit: for clarity, it's crucial both the `%20`'s AND the trailing `_1233456.html` are targeted, preferably using one single expression.**

The source can be targeted with

`^([\w]+%20)+.*\.html$` (multiple occurrences of `[\w]+%20`, followed by any character, followed by `.html`)

but I'm confused about how to specifically replace both the multiple occurrences of `%20` and the trailing '123456'. I'd guess this would be a shot in the right direction

`^(([\w]+)%20)+([\w]+)_[0-9]+\.html$`

`$1` being each occurrence of `([\w]+)%20`, `$2` being each occurrence of `[\w]+` within the first match, and `$3` being `[\w]+`, but I'm not getting the result I'm looking for (using Sublime Text for this):

```
string: a%20sentence%20divided%20by%20spaces_123456.html
search: ^(([\w]+)%20)+([\w]+)_[0-9]+\.html$
replace: $2+$3
expected result: a+sentence+divided+by+spaces
actual result: by+spaces
```

Any ideas where my line of thought goes awry?

Comment: What is the problem with simply replacing `%20` with `+`?

Comment: [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). `str = decodeURIComponent(str).replace(/\s+/g, '+');`

Comment: @ndn Mostly because of the trailing text (_123456.html) that also needs to be stripped using the same single expression, and therefore has to be part of the matching pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two regular expressions (there may be better solutions though):

```
var string ="a%20sentence%20divided%20by%20spaces_123456.html";
// replace %20 with +
var regex1 = '%20';
var re1 = new RegExp(regex1, 'g');
string = string.replace(re1, '+');
// trailing _12345
var regex2 = '([^_]+)_([^.]+)(\.html)$';
// match everything except an underscore and capture it in group 1
// underscore
// match everything except a dot
// match the file extension (html in this case) and capture it in group 3
var re2 = new RegExp(regex2);
string = string.replace(re2,'$1$3');
// replace the string with capture group 1 and 3
alert(string);
```

See [a JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4v4m83vo/1/) here.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however this doesn't strip away the trailing `_123456.html` - that's crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing parts of a string with different strings depending on what has been captured isn't something easily done with regex.
It can be done very easily using 2 regular expressions. However if you really want to do this with only 1 regex, here is a solution
**Solution with 1 regular expression :**

```
original_string = 'a%20sentence%20divided%20by%20spaces_123456.html'
searched_string = original_string + "+"
regex : '%20(?=[^\+]*(\+))|_[^_]*$'
replace : '$1'
result : a+sentence+divided+by+spaces
```

For the explanation :
The regex will search for either a "*%20*" followed by any string of character ending with "*+*" and capture the "*+*" **OR** every character after the last "*_*" and capture nothing
It will then replace the matched string by the capture string, which is a "*+*" if "*%20*" has been matched, and *nothing* if it's the end of the string
To work, this regex needs that the string contains a "*+*".
**That is why you NEED to concatenate it at the end of your string** (it will be erased by the regex at the end anyway)